# In Jest, how to run a piece of code to do mock before each describe block?

Tags: testing, jestjs

There are hundreds of jest test files, and in each unit test files there could be mutiple `describe` block.

Is there a config or method to automatically run a block of code to do mock and setup before each `describe` block?

I know a brutal method which is to put beforeAll() in each describe block in hundreds of files, but it is too much editing. I tried the [jest config object](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration), but didn't find any useful option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) config.

For example, I will mock the `axios` module for all test files. In order to make sure that your tests use the mocked `axios` instead of the actual `axios` implementation, update your `jest.config.js`, by adding `setupFileAfterEnv`, as follows:

`./a.test.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

describe('66341555 - a', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(axios)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

`./b.test.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

describe('66341555 - b', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(axios)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

`axios.mock.js`:

```js
jest.mock('axios');
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./axios.mock.js'],
};
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66341555/b.test.ts
 PASS  examples/66341555/a.test.ts

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.493 s, estimated 4 s
```

Here is a real-world example: https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock#example-usage